# What is the name of the bar in InteliJ, at the bottom of the Editor window

Tags: intellij-idea

It was disappear, the one in red:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breadcrumbs:

[image: bread crumbs]

File | Settings | Editor | General | Breadcrumbs:

[image: bread crumbs]